# Google Chrome screen flicker while playing a video with Windows 8

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8

Google Chrome screen flicker (frame drop) while playing a video with Windows 8. The video is fully streamed. Same video runs fine with Firefox and same with IE it only happens with Chrome.
Do anyone have any idea what would be causing this?